I am having issues with the user signup, authentication and views in django
I have a django app and i have created a function to login a user but it shows error
this is the view
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Username or Password is incorrect!!!")

    return render(request, 'login.html')


def LogoutPage(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

this is the html code
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-form">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign up here</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

this is the url
path('login/', userview.loginpage, name='loginpage'),
this is the error shown
TypeError at /login/
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version:     4.2.11
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:
login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
i have added the user but still it asks or user argument. i restarted but it was the same

Why is your request GET request.
and all your code regarding authentication is request.POST
can you check network traffic in chrome.
and paste request in view to debug.

The error message you encountered is a TypeError message which indicated a missing positional argument of your Python function, login().
Here is the updated version of your code:

def loginpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            # this Boolean user call-check is required for the authentication process.
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Username or Password is incorrect!!!")

    return render(request, 'login.html')

However, ensure that your urls.py file path points to the exact view because I don't understand where the `userview.loginpage` is from, which not quite conventional in Django, is it not supposed to be something like `views.loginpage`?

If the error persists which I doubt, I would like to see your User model class, and whether you used a custom User model or not. And do note that CBV approach is far productive in this context imo because Django has a nicer way of handling this issue in the backend via from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views and using the LoginView class.
